# Books about incremental data clustering

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, references, data-mining

Does anyone have a suggestion of any relatively recent and good book about data clustering?
More specifically, I'm looking for incremental clustering.

Comment: Chapter [7 Clustering](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds/ch7.pdf) from the free book [Mining of Massive Datasets](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/mmds.html), and 7.6 Clustering for Streams and Parallelism might interest you.

Comment: Great one, chapter 7.6 seems interesting for me (even if it is somehow brief), I'll take a look at it ! (of course, I would prefered the whole book to be on this specific subject)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a field that is this actively researched, a book will be quickly out of date. Just as with regular clustering: most books still discuss just hierarchical clustering, k-means and EM.

There is a book by C.C.Aggarwal, "Data streams: models and algorithms". Chapter 2 is on clustering.

It is better to check for recent publications in this field, in particular survey articles.

There is one survey from 2009: Alireza Rezaei Mahdiraji, "Clustering data stream: A survey of algorithms". But you will want look at newer methods than these, too.

Answer (score 0):

Not a book, but a [paper](http://books.nips.cc/papers/files/nips22/NIPS2009_1085.pdf) on this area.

> Ailon, Nir, Ragesh Jaiswal & Claire Monteleoni. 2009. Streaming
>   k-means approximation. In *Advances in Neural Information Processing
>   Systems*.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you [chapter 8](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/ch8.pdf) from "Cluster Analysis: Basic Concepts and Algorithms" 
It provides a very definite overview on clustering, including Agglomerative Clustering, that we can count as incremental clustering.